# Google Analytics - Language (not set) & Sharebutton.to

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I currently manage quite a few Google Analytics accounts for different websites and am trying to work out how to remove certain Anayltics spam from these accounts. I have previously added filters like excluding Russia visitors as the businesses are local UK based but I am now getting a lot of traffic from:

Language - not set
&
Page - sharebutton.to

If i was to exlucde the above would that get rid of any actual visitors as well as spam or will it get rid of 100% spam?

If someone could help with this that would be brilliant.

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Filters based on countries or the name of the spam are not efficient because both can be easily changed by the spammers.

Also, **it isn't possible to filter the (not set) entries in Analytics**, this label is added after the visit is recorded when Analytics doesn't find a value for that dimension.

Instead what you should use

- **One hostname filter**, this will help prevent the majority of the spam, whether it shows as referral, page, language, etc. and independently of the name used by the spammer.
- A **source filter for the sneaky** crawlers which are far less frequent.

Here you will find [detailed instructions on how to create the hostname filter](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) and other measures you can take to prevent fake traffic.